# why does LAST_INSERT_ID() returns foreign key

Tags: mysql

Im using mysql database. When i add some sample data inside my database when i want to return the last insert id as follow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM facturatiedatabase.tblinvoice;
```

It returns customersID instead.

This the table i'm using.

```
CREATE TABLE tblInvoice (       
        invoiceID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        customerID INT,
        totalPriceExcl decimal(65,2),
        vat decimal(65,2),
        totalPriceIncl decimal(65,2),
        conditionState VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'In progress' ,
        createDate Date,
        invoiceNumber int ,
        CONSTRAINT FK_customerID_Invoice FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES tblCustomers(customerID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax or is this a common problem? And is there a workaround ?

Comment: Are you doing any insert into the customer table as well ?

Comment: No i do not insert any data in the customer table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using it wrongly.

From the docs:

> LAST_INSERT_ID() (with no argument) returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value
>   representing the first automatically generated value that was set for
>   an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT
>   statement to affect such a column. For example, after inserting a row
>   that generates an AUTO_INCREMENT value, you can get the value like
>   this:

Note the example doesn't query a table. It's based on the current connection.

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
        -> 195
```

If you do an insert into `tblInvoice` then run `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` you'll get back the `invoiceID`.

So a working example would be:

```
INSERT INTO tblInvoice (columns) VALUES (data);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- The invoiceID generated from above insert
```

If what you really want is the last created invoice ID, try:

```
SELECT MAX(invoiceID) FROM tblInvoice
```

Not perfect, but should be enough for your needs.